# How to set color in the Theme to primary in flutter?

Tags: flutter, colors

I want to set a color in my Theme to the primary color.
When the primary color changes, so should the other color.

I know how to assign a hardcoded color to any color in the Theme.
But I don't know how to dynamically reference the primary color.

Here's what I tried:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        textTheme: const TextTheme(titleLarge: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    ));

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('ok', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to refer primary color instead of setting black color?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `Colors.primaries`

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own subclass of `ThemeData` and override the getter for the appropriate color to return the primary color instead.

```dart
class CustomThemeData extends ThemeData
{
  // Implement appropriate constructor or factory
  // ...

  // Then override getter to return the primary color
  @override
  Color get cardColor => this.primaryColor;
}
```

And use it when running your app

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  theme: CustomThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    textTheme: const TextTheme(titleLarge: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(),
));
```

Comment: ThemeData has only factory constructors. Is it possible to extend it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to change text color is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  var themeData = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
  );
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: themeData.copyWith(
        textTheme: themeData.textTheme.copyWith(
            titleLarge: themeData.textTheme.titleLarge
                ?.copyWith(color: themeData.primaryColor))),
    home: const MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('ok', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Material 3 is default theme on Flutter 3.16. set **useMaterial3: false** in ThemeData to disable it.

```
MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'ISI DSC',
   theme: ThemeData(
   useMaterial3: false,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create the ColorScheme in advance, and then you can reference it in the theme.

So in your case:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//chose your color scheme
ColorScheme appColors = ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green[900]!);


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorScheme: appColors,//<--this
        textTheme: const TextTheme(titleLarge: TextStyle(color: appColors.primary)),//<--and this
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    ));

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('ok', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes

```
Theme(
  // Create a unique theme with `ThemeData`.
  data: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.pink,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Remember: *As of the Flutter 3.16 release, Material 3 is Flutter’s default theme.*

Comment: How does this answer the question? The author asked to explicitly not use a hardcoded color and have a dynamic reference instead